I need write a lead sheet with repeats, different lyrics for each repeat, the chorus and chords
I have this snipped code that resembles the work that I need to make:
\version "2.22.0"

musicA = \relative c' {
  \repeat volta 2 {
    a1 
    b2 c2 
    d4 e f g
  }
  \alternative {
    { b2 c2}
    {b2 }
  }
}

musicCoro = \relative c' { %chorus first time once
  g' c 
  c4 b a g a2 
}

letraA = \lyricmode { 
  A b c d e f g b c
}

letraAone = \lyricmode {
  La si do re mi fa sol 
  \skip 2 \skip 2
  si 
}

letraAtwo = \lyricmode {
  this is the new ly rics for fi nal
}

letraAthree = \lyricmode { 
  this is the last ly rics for so~ong
}

letraCoro = \lyricmode {
  He re - the cho rus -
}

acordesA = \chordmode {
  \repeat volta 2 {a1:m g2 c2 g1}
  \alternative {
    {g2 c2}
    {g2 }
  }
}

acordesCoro = \chordmode {
  c2 a1:m f1
}

<<
  \new ChordNames {\acordesA \acordesCoro \acordesA \acordesCoro}
  \new Voice = "A" {\musicA \musicCoro \musicA
                    \repeat volta 2 { \musicCoro }
  }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto A \letraA
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto A {
    \letraAone \letraCoro 
    <<
      \letraAtwo
      \letraAthree %this doesn't appear
  >> } 
>>

but I can't get the lyrics for the final parts to appear, and same for the last chorus.

Your code is not working as << ... >> with Lyrics does not work. To get what I think you want, do something like this:
<<
  \new ChordNames {\acordesA \acordesCoro \acordesA \acordesCoro}
  \new Voice = "A" {\musicA \musicCoro \musicA
                    \repeat volta 2 { \musicCoro }
  }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto A \letraA
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto A { \letraAone \letraCoro \letraAtwo }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto A { \repeat unfold 17 \skip4 \letraAthree } 
>>


Thanks @Lazy. With this strategy works fine. A question related: Do not exists a better manner to write this type of code? where you  wouldn't have to count the number of measures for example. Thanks a lot!

@LuisSalazar Yes, there is. You could use different named Voices and assign the Lyrics to the corresponding parts.

I don't know exactly but I will try and return after here with more questions. Thanks.

Hi @Lazy I make this: <<
\new ChordNames {\acordesA  }
\new Voice = "A" {\musicA}
\new Lyrics  \lyricsto A \letraA
\new Lyrics \lyricsto A \letraAone
\new ChordNames \acordesCoro
\new Voice = "Coro" {\musicCoro}
\new Lyrics \lyricsto Coro \letraCoro



but it creates a new Staff and don't put the chorus next to the music.

To solve this question I find the next solution (adapted from an example in the snnipets documentation):
\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames {\acordesA \acordesCoro \acordesA }
    \new Staff {
      \context Voice = "main" { \musicA }
      \context Voice = "chorus" { \musicCoro }
      \context Voice = "mainTwo" { \musicA }
    }
    \new Lyrics = "lyricsI" { 
      \lyricsto "main"  \letraA 
    }
    \new Lyrics = "lyricsII" { 
      \lyricsto "main"  \letraAone 
    }
    \new Lyrics = "refrain" {
      \lyricsto "chorus" \letraCoro
    }
    \new Lyrics = "lyricsIII" {
      \lyricsto "mainTwo" \letraAtwo
    }
    \new Lyrics = "lyricsIV" {
      \lyricsto "mainTwo" \letraAthree
    }    
  >>
}

This strategy permits to avoid the counting of measures in the song.
